# How to sent parameter in SwipeableDrawer of material ui in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

This is my SwipeableDrawer of material-ui

```
const sideList = (
</List>
  <ListItem button component={Link} to="/todos">
    <ListItemText primary="Todos" />
  </ListItem>
</List>
)
```

```
<SwipeableDrawer
  open={this.state.left}
  onClose={this.toggleDrawer('left', false)}
  onOpen={this.toggleDrawer('left', true)}
>
<div tabIndex={0}
  onClick={this.toggleDrawer('left', false)}
  {sideList}
</div>
</SwipeableDrawer>
```

I need to set the `dashboard` value here based on the list I choose'

```
toggleDrawer = (side, open) => () => {
 this.setState({
    [side]: open,
    dashboard: 
 });
};
```

I have a menu like this:

```
{this.state.dashboard}
```

How do I set the value of dashboard equal to 'Todo'? As that is what I have selected from the list.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by adding a `onClick()` function to the List element, and a `setState` in this click function so it changes the state of your component, like this:

```
state = {
  left: false,
  dashboard: 'none_yet',
};
```

```
changeDashboardState = (dashboardValue) => {
  this.setState({
    dashboard: dashboardValue,
  }) 
}
```

```
<List>
  {["Inbox", "Starred", "Send email", "Drafts"].map((text, index) => (
    <ListItem button key={text} onClick={() => this.changeDashboardState(text)}>
      <ListItemText primary={text} />
    </ListItem>
  ))}
</List>
```

[image]

This way you will be able to change the state by clicking in any list element. Also I implemented it to test, you can see it in this [git repository](https://github.com/PedrinhowVieira/SwipeableDrawerExample/blob/master/src/App.js)